# Accessing the "_embedded" data in spring data REST interface

Tags: java, json, spring, d3.js

The project is a visual analysis of business data, MongoDB through Spring Data, REST interface, then d3.js.

On the database level, my data looks like this:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58ac466160fb39e5e8dc8b70"),
    "dots" : {
        "x" : 4,
        "y" : 3
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58ac468060fb39e5e8dc8b7e"),
    "squares" : {
        "x" : 12,
        "y" : 2
    }
}
```

The REST interface (spring) delivers this:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "JSON" : [ {
      "squares" : null,
      "dots" : {
        "dot" : {
          "x" : 4,
          "y" : 3
        }
      },
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/JSON/58ac466160fb39e5e8dc8b70"
        },
        "jSON" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/JSON/58ac466160fb39e5e8dc8b70"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "squares" : {
        "square" : {
          "x" : 12,
          "y" : 2
        }
      },
      "dots" : null,
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/JSON/58ac468060fb39e5e8dc8b7e"
        },
        "jSON" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/JSON/58ac468060fb39e5e8dc8b7e"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/JSON"
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile/JSON"
    }
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 2,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

Now I'm having trouble accessing this for processing in d3.js for visualization, whatever way I try to access the data, I only get "undefined" with no values back on the console.

Should I reformat to get rid of the "_embedded" part, or to "flatten" the data generally, or do I need a specific way to access it?

As of now, I'm just using "d3.json("/JSON")" to access the interface, but can't extract any data.

Comment: If I request the same repository in jQuery AJAX, I get a response of three objects with the data nested inside them. Can't get that to work with d3.js, any ideas?